# VueJS: Elements-UI el-select: How to get selectedLabel value?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, element, element-ui

I have a filter by state dropdown,

```html
<el-form-item label="State" prop="state"> 
<el-select v-model="listQuery.state" filterable placeholder="Select State" @change="getCityList" > 
<el-option v-for="item in stateList" :key="item.name" :label="item.name" :value="item.code" ></el-option> 
</el-select> 
</el-form-item>
<el-tag
    :key="tag"
    v-for="tag in tags"
    closable
    :disable-transitions="true"
    @close="handleClose(tag)"
  >{{tag}}</el-tag>
```

On select I'm sending the code of the state to the api and Im using closable el-tag to show the state name so that user can remove the filter. There also I'm getting the code, but I want to show the state name instead. Is there anyway to get the key or label of the selected option?
Please help me out from this.

Here is the screenshot,

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the code for the closable el-tag?

Comment: @SBylemans I have updated my code, please have a look..

Comment: I'm not that familiar with vue, but when you select a value, it is added to the tags object?

Comment: I know how to do in javascript and Vuejs, but I'm using Element-ui so I want to use that select component to get the selected value. If you're familiar with Elements you can understand it easily.

Comment: Are you filling the `tags` object somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The value binding in the select can be the javascript object “item”, it doesn’t need to be “item.code”.  The requirement for that (binding the value to a js object) is that you must bind :key and the value bound to key must be unique.